# cant login to facebook developer app, getting redirected to my facebook page instead

Tags: facebook

I am developing apps for android smartphones. There is a "social" SDK to integrate with facebook. As usual, the SDK requires to setup a facebook up for getting the app id from facebook.
So, I have a facebook community page (besides my personal page).
So, I go to developers.facebook.com. Follow the links "Getting started" until I am on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ There is a link "Register your Android App with Facebook", I follow it to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#register . There is a link "create a new app on Facebook". When I click it one of too (equally bad things happens): Instead of getting to the "Create App" page:

1. If I am already logged in to my facebook community page, I will be redirected to that page.
2. If I am not logged in, facebook requires me to login in and afterwards redirects me to my community page.

So I can not reach the "Create app dialog" on developers.facebook.com.

What I am missing here? I tried with a Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer.
Any help is very much appreciated, I am new to facebook apps, my domain is actually Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read somewhere that you cant create an app for a business page but must have a user account. So have a user account then create a page. at that point you should be able to access the app developer section

Comment: Seems to be correct. From my user account, I can access the developer section. How I hate it, when docs aren't complete.