# I can not access developers.facebook.com

Tags: facebook

### Problem

I am trying to access [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) with a *user account*, but I only get a blank page. I read some articles on how to become a Facebook developer. According to the articles you have to have at least one friend, a verified account  and you have to add the Facebook developer app to your account. Except for adding the developer app I did all of that. When I search for the developer app I and try to visit the page of the developer app I get redirected to my 'home' page (see Appendix).

There are a lot of questions on Stackoverflow that describe the exact same behavior. For instance:

1. [how do I access facebook developer app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763109/how-do-i-access-facebook-developer-app)
2. [cant login to facebook developer app, getting redirected to my facebook page instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066711/cant-login-to-facebook-developer-app-getting-redirected-to-my-facebook-page-ins)

They all state that the problem is that you can't become a developer if you use a *business* or *page* account. So I tried to find out if my account is of such a type. The Facebook documentation says:

> Business accounts are designed for people who only want to use Facebook to administer Pages and their ad campaigns. You can use a business account to view all the Pages and Social Ads you've created. You can also see public info about other people on Facebook from a business account, but you can't interact with those people outside the context of your Page. And, unlike personal accounts, business accounts can't be found in search, send or receive friend requests or create/develop apps. ([link](http://www.facebook.com/help/131976240210052))

Since I added another account as friend I don't think that the account is a *business* or *page* account.

### What I have tried so far

First I deleted all my cookies to be sure that those are not the problem. I also tried another browser (Chrome 21 and Firefox 14). Accessing sub pages of developers.facebook.com also result in a redirect to my home page.

### Questions

1. How can I add the developer app to my account?
2. How can I access developers.facebook.com?

### Appendix

[image: Adding the Facebook developer app to your account]

Comment: Don't know why people downvote posts without leaving a comment. I tried hard to write this question as precise and clear as possible. I also answered the question, so that other people with the same problem    can get an answer faster than I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long time I think I found the problem. The account I was given was in fact a *user* account. But it was a *test user* account. Those accounts are very limited and can't be used to access [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com). You can read more about test users in the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/).

I also wrote:

> Since I added another account as friend I don't think that the account is a business or page account.

Funny thing is that the account I added also is a *test user* account. And those can friend each other but not *real* accounts.